# How do I remove the padding around a Salesforce Lightning Community page?

Tags: css, lightning-community

Lightning community pages have a wrapper `div` which has `padding: 0.75rem` all around the page.

```
<div class="slds-col--padded contentRegion comm-layout-column"> 
all content here
</div>
```

I tried to remove the padding by adding CSS to a lightning component it's restricted to only work within the bounds of the lightning component, so therefore cannot affect anything outside of it.

How do I remove the padding from the page wrapper `div`?

Comment: you will have to be more specific in regards to what you mean by a community page - and if possible include a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set some custom CSS properties which apply to your community in the settings of the community(rather than the actual Lightning component).

If you can accurately target that wrapper div, you should be able to change the padding.

Here is some documentation on how to go about this:

- [Override Template Elements with Custom CSS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm)

Screenshot:

[image]